# Suppress unicode prefix on strings when using pprint

Tags: python, pprint

Is there any clean way to supress the unicode character prefix when printing an object using the pprint module?

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint({u'foo': u'bar', u'baz': [u'apple', u'orange', u'pear', u'guava', u'banana'], u'hello': u'world'})
{u'baz': [u'apple', u'orange', u'pear', u'guava', u'banana'],
 u'foo': u'bar',
 u'hello': u'world'}
```

This looks pretty ugly. Is there any way to print the __str__ value of each object, instead of the __repr__?

Comment: If you print the `__str__` of each object, you won't get the quotes either. Is that really what you want?

Comment: yes, that's what i want

Comment: Then why didn't you say so, and why did you accept an answer that doesn't remove the quotes?

Comment: The accepted answer is programmable, so you can adapt it to whatever format you need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It could be done by overriding the format method of the PrettyPrinter object, and casting any unicode object to string:

```
import pprint

def my_safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level):
    typ = pprint._type(object)
    if typ is unicode:
        object = str(object)
    return pprint._safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level)

printer = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
printer.format = my_safe_repr
printer.pprint({u'foo': u'bar', u'baz': [u'apple', u'orange', u'pear', u'guava', u'banana'], u'hello': u'world'})
```

which gives:

```
{'baz': ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'guava', 'banana'],
 'foo': 'bar',
 'hello': 'world'}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it gives exception 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
when i.e. {u'ключ': u'значение'}

Comment: Indeed, your strings are pure unicode strings, so they cannot be cast to ASCII. You should not consider `removing the unicode prefix`, because it makes no sense in your case.

Comment: I solved this problem by encoding value before convert it into str

Answer (score 2):

This may be too much, but one possible way is to implement a wrapper over the output stream:

```
import pprint,sys,re

class writer :
    def write(self, text):
        text=re.sub(r'u\'([^\']*)\'', r'\1',text)
        sys.stdout.write(text)

wrt=writer()
d = { u'foo': u'bar', u'baz':
        [u'apple', u'orange', u'pear', u'guava', u'banana'],
        u'hello': u'world'}
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(stream=wrt)

pp.pprint(d)
```

*Output:*

```
{baz: [apple, orange, pear, guava, banana],
 foo: bar,
 hello: world}
```

It is also possible to put quotes inside parents to have single quotes around strings, e,g, 'foo' : 'bar':

```
text=re.sub(r'u(\'[^\']*\')', r'\1',text)
```

This gives:

```
{'baz': ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'guava', 'banana'],
 'foo': 'bar',
 'hello': 'world'}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, [pprint](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) prints the representation. It's not for making pretty end-user output, but for printing Python objects in a readable way.

> The pprint module provides a capability to “pretty-print” arbitrary
>   Python data structures in a form which can be used as input to the
>   interpreter.

Comment: Any good alternative way to print a large, nested structure in a readable way?

Comment: Hmm, I found the [prettyprint](https://github.com/taichino/prettyprint) module which looks pretty nice.

Comment: interesting answer @jterrace! cooked down this is just: use `print(json.dumps())`

Answer (score 1):

(Many years later answer)

Just use python3.   All standard strings are unicode by default, so no u prefix.